# Ruby - Reading from multiple sockets (irc bot)

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sockets, irc, connection

I'm trying to make an IRC bot that connects to multiple servers, and I'm having trouble reading from all the sockets at once.

My current code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby
    require 'socket'

    servers = ["irc.chat4all.org"]

    def connect(server, port, count)
            puts "connecting to #{server}..."
                    @socket[count] = TCPSocket.open(server, port)
                    say("NICK link_hub", count)
                    say("USER link_hub 0 * link_hub", count)
                    read_data(count)
    end

    def say(msg, count)
            @socket[count.to_i].puts msg.to_s
    end

    def say_channel(msg, count)
            @socket[count.to_i].puts("PRIVMSG #test :"+msg.to_s)
    end


    def read_data(count)
            until @socket[count].eof? do
                    msg = @socket[count].gets
                    puts msg
                    if msg.match(/^PING :(.*)$/)
                            say("PONG #{$~[1]}", count)
                            say("JOIN #test", count)
                            next
                    end
                    if msg.match(/`test/)
                            say_channel("connecting to efnet...", count)
                            Thread.new {
                            connect("irc.efnet.nl", 6667, count)
                            }
                    end
            end
    end

    conn = []
    count = 0
    @socket = []
    servers.each do |server|
            connect(server, 6667, count)
            count += 1
    end
```

The problem is that when I send the command '`test', it connects to efnet, but it wont read the other socket anymore even though im running the new connection in a thread. I just want to read from both sockets at the same time. (the variable 'count' is the socket number)

Can anyone help me out? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need paralelism for that.

```
pids = []
servers.each do |server|
    pids << fork do
      connect(server, 6667, count)
      count += 1
    end
end
pids.each{|pid| Process.wait pid}
```

You might want to read about processes, threads and other operational system topics.